# Jacobi matrix of linear mapping

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

The task is to calculate the following linear mapping Jacobi matrix: 
$$x=uvw, y=uv-uvw, z=v-uv$$
Unfortunately, due to the coronavirus I've missed several classes devoted to this topic and while I've understood what Jacobi matrix itself stands for, I have no idea what $u, v, w$ are. Would be glad to get any hint or solution with explanations.

Comment: I imagine that $x,y,z$ are 3 real maps of the real three variables $u,v,w$. So you're asked to compute the Jacobi matrix of the map $(u,v,w) \mapsto (uvw, uv-uvw,v-uv)$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net, and how to do that?..

Comment: I suggest that you read carefully this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant).

Comment: These equations are met in probability in connection with Dirichlet distribution : see page 2 second column of (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.3436.pdf)

Comment: Compute the 9 partial derivatives... and arrange them in a matrix...

Comment: By the way, the transformation isn't linear : example of a linear transform : $x=2u+3v-w,y=4u,z=u+v+w$

Comment: @JeanMarie, yeah, accidentally added "linear", which of course has nothing to do here..